# Remove a section based on attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to remove a section based on the attribute chosen in the xml file. I tried many places but couldn't find the solution for this one. Here is my issue:

I have 2 sections in my xml file and I am trying to filter one section based on the attribute "name" using XSLT.

Current XML

```
   <BindingSection>
      <Bindings name="temp">
        <add type="type" assembly="test Assembly"  dst="destination" />
      </Bindings>

      <Bindings name="final">
       <add type="type" assembly="test Assembly"  dst="destination" />
      </Bindings>
 </BindingSection>
```

If I choose "temp", then the Bindings Section with "final" should be removed from the XML file and result should be like below.

Desired XML

```
 <BindingSection>
      <Bindings name="temp">
        <add type="type" assembly="test Assembly"  dst="destination" />
      </Bindings>
 </BindingSection>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"If I choose "temp""* Where would this choice be made?

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer. I hope I've fully understood your request. Keep the section corresponding the parameter you declared in the XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="var">temp</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="Bindings">
  <xsl:if test="@name=$var">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/nbssZvq

Comment: yes. This works for me. Thanks so much for the help.